# How to mix Spring and blueprint in OSGi container?

Tags: osgi, fuseesb, spring-dm

I see that blueprint is better supported and will be widely adopted by many OSGi containers including JBoss Fuse. Sadly, Spring has many features that seem hard to implement in current blueprint (CMIIW). The features like: annotation for ehcache (e.g. cache:annotation-driven), contextAware beans.

My question is, is it possible to mix them (Spring DM and blueprint)? If it is, how? Is there any working codes out there?

FYI, I left Spring DM for one reason: blueprint as new standard

Lately, I realized that distributed OSGi service is supported when using Spring DM.

Thanks

Comment: Actually Spring DM was renamed Gemini Blueprint, and is still the RI (Reference Implementation) for the Blueprint specification. However Gemini is essentially abandonware now since VMware stopped working on it and left the OSGi Alliance.

Comment: Implementing things like annotation driven caching in OSGI should be agnostic to the specific technology being used (Spring-DM, Blueprint, DS). Also, the only context to be aware of is the BundleContext, which you can get in Blueprint or from an Activator or DS.

Comment: Currently annotation handling is done by spring. So while it would be nice to have this technology independent it is not the case. I currently simply live with the fact that blueprint is missing some features but we need to address this. On the other hand spring aggregated too many features over time. So have the most necessary things would be good enough to me. In the end I hope for the JEE annotation model to be available in OSGi.

Comment: I tried to include <cache:annotation> inside the <blueprint> element. As it started, it said "Grace" and "The mybundle.hello is waiting for namespace handlers [http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache]". I haven't seen any working samples about mixing them. Could it be that, OSGi blueprint is not complex production ready?

Comment: If you aren't using Spring DM or Gemini, you can't really mix Spring namespaces with Blueprint namespaces.